# Determine network usage per users

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way to monitor network activity per user in vb.net?

Basically something that mimics the remote desktop services manager, any information would be great,

Thanks

Comment: I am just in the process of researching this, I really have no idea where to start and have just been searching google. I am new to VB.Net and have never attempted anything like this before. Any information would be great even information such as where to loop or a brief outline of what needs to be done.

Comment: Good. I usually like to make such comments for new users when they tend to respond. Have you written/used any code about network monitoring? Answering this would realize that how you can be guided?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no not to this point, but i am a quick learner. My google searches seem to come back with more off the shelf products then anything else. Any insight would be extremely helpful even a starting point.

Comment: Googling of Process Monitor c# resulted for me : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38438/Monitoring-Process-Statistics-in-C-WPF. Remember That c# is easily convertable into vb here : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/. I have no knowledge in this domain, however I felt it my duty to provide you some general guidance. Remember asking guidance for a solution is badly minded by most of members, just every asker is supposed to ask some problem within a solution by sharing the context of problem and some code in which there is problem

Comment: Thank you this is something i can work from,

Comment: I really appreciate your courage and confidence. God bless you...

Comment: So i am basically at a deadend with this now and there seems to be next to no information on how to do this anywhere